# fullcalendar with laravel6 - error saying Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at addDefs

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar, laravel-6

I am trying to use fullcalendar in one of my laravel6 project and got stuck.
The document I am following is here:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6

I created a brand new laravel6 project, and ran the following command.

```
npm install --save @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid
```

Then I edited resources/js/app.js like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.fc_core = require('@fullcalendar/core');
window.fc_daygrid = require('@fullcalendar/daygrid');
```

I added the following codes at the last part of the default view of view/welcome.blade.php

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new fc_core.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ fc_daygrid.dayGridPlugin ]
        });

        calendar.render();
    });

</script>
```

Lastly, I compiled resources by the following command.

```
npm run dev
```

Laravel Mix shows successful compile. However, when I access to the public directory via Apache on Xampp, Javascript doesn't work and shows the following error message.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at addDefs (app.js:5774)
    at buildPluginHooks (app.js:5782)
    at CalendarDataManager.buildPluginHooks (app.js:5793)
    at CalendarDataManager../node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js.CalendarDataManager.processRawCalendarOptions (app.js:7539)
    at CalendarDataManager../node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js.CalendarDataManager._computeOptionsData (app.js:7512)
    at CalendarDataManager.computeOptionsData (app.js:1310)
    at new CalendarDataManager (app.js:7344)
    at new Calendar (app.js:10131)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):96)
```

I have no idea for how to resolve this error. Can anyone please help me out of this?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Sorry there's a typo. 
"Then I edited public/js/app.js like this:" -> "Then I edited resources/js/app.js like this:"

Comment: Your question has an "edit" button under it. Use that to correct typos, instead of hiding the corrections in comments. Thanks.